# Ajax calls prevent massive requests calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Which is the best way/plugin/method to prevent users launching too many xhr request by clicking many times/sequentially ( :|) on a xhr button?

i'm using jQuery.

Comment: Disabling the button after first click until the request returns?

Comment: i just toggle button disabled/enabled on beforeSend and success ;)  there is no simple way to set some kind of timeout between clicks? :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I usually do:

```
$("button").click(function(e){
    var $this = $(this);
    if(!$this.data("ajaxCall")){
        var xhr = $.ajax({
            options here,
            complete: function(){
                $this.removeData("ajaxCall");
            }
        });
        $this.data("ajaxCall", xhr)
    }
});
```

Comment: uhmmmm.... complete: i think is a step more that i didn't considered ... mmmm :) thx

Answer (score 1):

you could remove the click event at the start of your function, and then add the click event back.

Comment: so the user will click on the button and nothing will happen, he won't understand why

Comment: well disabling/enabling button i think is the same :P not?

Comment: that's how it should work. If the user click 100 times a button only one call will go through you don't need to notify the user about that and I think it is much better then disable the button where you could have nasty issue in the case something happen and the button doesn't get enable back

Comment: uhmmm ... that's true.  The fact is i would like to set a timeout between calls , if a request takes 0.0.5 seconds i think you will see no differences if button enabled/disabled or event is there or not :P ... i mean setting a min timeout like 0.500 secs for a call could be great for me, also if xhr takes less less less time to complete :P

Comment: a sort of min time limit for calls :P

Comment: I would not raccomand you to go down this road. Removing and adding an event won't lead the performance and you can use it for all your call.
The web environment can be very nasty sometime: what if a call that usually takes 0.001ms takes 5 sec to be execute maybe because the net is slowing down?

Comment: ispuk, I want to disable your 'colon' and 'P' buttons :P

Answer (score 1):

You can disable your button.

```
$('.someElement').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Comment: does it works for <a> buttons? :P  for <input> or <button> is what i'm doing right now ;)

Comment: why are you using a button ? <a> are here for links, if you want to ouput your button as a link, use a input tag (or button) + css.

Comment: uhm don't you matter on what i do i'm not a guru :)), just i would like to know if attr('disabled','disabled') will work if added to <a> element :P, i think  yes rihgt?

Comment: No one is a guru here, I just suggested that you use the right html tag for the right thing. And no you can't call disable on an anchor I think, test it but ...